# Getting different results for admin versus non-admin user on view when there is a relationship

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have a `view` that shows the two newest articles with specific taxonomy rules. We got a new requirement to now exclude articles that are linked via `entity reference`.

So I added the relationship for referencing entities. With just the relationship in place and no filters added, non-admin users only see articles that are related (the relationship is not set to required).

When I add the filter that node ID of the related (referencing) articles should be NULL, non-admin users see nothing, but admin users see the results as they should be.

What can explain the discrepancy and what can fix it?

Drupal 7

Comment: sounds like a permissions issue - do you have any content access modules or similar installed? Views usually honours permission control on nodes, so if the user does not have permission to see the content, it won't show in views

Comment: That would make sense for this case if it wasn't showing the data without the relationship. But it does show the data then. The content that references it is shown in a separate view right above.

Comment: that is definitely odd - if it were me (given the somewhat appearance of a permissions problem) I would create a new role, give it all permissions and see if a user with that role can view it properly.  If the user can, start taking away permissions until it fails - it would narrow down the problem (if it was or related to a permissions issue)

Comment: I got devel to output the query and I'm seeing this which isn't in the query when run by admin: SELECT na.nid AS nid FROM node_access. I'm not sure where this is set. I don't have any modules called node access, so I image it's set somewhere else.

Comment: Devel has a block that will show node access settings on each node, you could find out more about the issue that way. You may need to set your permissions correctly and rebuild the node access settings.

Comment: that's because admin by default has the permission to bypass all content access control, so Views doesn't even include it in the query - even including it though doesn't mean that's the problem - I will keep thinking about it, but nothing else comes to mind as a culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this problem is related to this drupal bug https://www.drupal.org/node/1349080 .

Solution: Edit your view > Right column "Advanced" > Query settings: check "Disable Query Rewriting"

Simple explanation for the bug and the solution https://www.drupal.org/node/1276450#comment-10451305, quote the comment below

> Actually, this is a bug, in Drupal core, and there is a fix, in
>   #1349080: node_access breaks any query that has node table appearing twice with a left join. It just has not been committed to Drupal core
>   yet, because the fix is a bit brittle and may not work in all corner
>   cases. It has to do with the node_access system, and any view that
>   connects the node table or an entity table multiple times (e.g. via a
>   relationship), when there is any access module enabled on the site,
>   will trigger it.
>
> Disabling SQL rewriting will bypass the issue, and should be entirely
>   safe to do, unless you have some access rules you want to enforce
>   (such as products in an OG group that only members of that group
>   should be able to see) -- in which case you can usually address that
>   by adding your own explicit filter to the view instead of relying on
>   the core node access to filter it out for you.
>
> If all your products are public, there's no need for this node_access
>   check.

Cheers